# Unable to access HSQLDB database in spring-boot application using Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hsqldb, spring-boot

In my current spring-boot application, I am trying use hibernate to access a HSQLDB database. I have this configuration class for hibernate:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.spring.app" })
public class HibernateConfig {

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.spring.app.model" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource restDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      String db_url = System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"testedb";

      dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:file:"+db_url);
      dataSource.setUsername("sa");
      dataSource.setPassword("");

      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
      return txManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties hibernateProperties() {
      return new Properties() {
         /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "import.sql");
            setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
         }
      };
   }
}
```

but when I run the application, I see this message in console when the database scheme should be exported:

```
2014-10-29 09:38:26.251  INFO 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2014-10-29 09:38:26.261 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table role_members drop constraint FK_1r16pyyykpv1v6s973ahavdf8
2014-10-29 09:38:26.261 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.ROLE_MEMBERS
2014-10-29 09:38:26.261 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table role_members drop constraint FK_r6a4sbd3nbgk795exs9p5s6sr
2014-10-29 09:38:26.261 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.ROLE_MEMBERS
2014-10-29 09:38:26.262 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table role_permissions drop constraint FK_ipe67mj8dm7kxw2hcdxrixfaa
2014-10-29 09:38:26.262 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.ROLE_PERMISSIONS
2014-10-29 09:38:26.262 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table role_permissions drop constraint FK_cpxi8h0vi43j90938fdt729p7
2014-10-29 09:38:26.263 ERROR 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.ROLE_PERMISSIONS
2014-10-29 09:38:26.270  INFO 16405 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

I try use both `sa` or `SA` for username, without success. Also, I have this `import.sql` file on my classpath:

```
INSERT INTO role VALUES (1, 'admin');
INSERT INTO permission VALUES (1, 'admin');
INSERT INTO role_permissions VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO usuario VALUES (1, 'klebermo', 'pwd', 'Kleber', 'Mota', 'kleber@mail');
INSERT INTO role_members VALUES (1,1);
```

but no data is being inserted on the database (when I try login in the application, I get a message "user not found".

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you manually configuring your data source? You should just specify the data source properties in your application.yml and let Spring Boot configure it for you (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Bohuslav. If it helps, I just needed to put the following in application.properties to configure access to MySQL:

```
#
## Database configuration
#
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring
spring.datasource.username: spring
spring.datasource.password: spring
spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.jpa.database: MYSQL
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do this with java code, with allow me to keep the programa multiplataform (by using something like: `String db_url = System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"testedb"`) for the name of the database

Comment: Indeed there is, you can use system properties in your application.yml (or .properties) with this syntax: `my.property: ${user.home}${file.separator}testedb`